# How can i split an incoming data in arduino?

Tags: serial-data

So  for my arduino project I need to split this line of servos data

```
180 0 0 0 90 90 0
```

Which would be parsed as:

```
servo position1 servo positin2 servo positin3 ...servo position 6
```

in to separate servo values, but i am new at arduino and c typе languges so a little bit help will be very good. So my question is how can I split these values up?

Comment: You can use parseInt() function as well. It looks for next valid integer after one delimiter.
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning string formatted data can be done with `sscanf` ([docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)). It takes format strings just like `printf()` does, but instead of printing formatted data, it parses formatted data into the given variables.

For example,

```cpp
String input = "180 0 0 0 90 90 0";
//parse input (6 integers)
int servoPositions[6];
int numScanned = sscanf (input.c_str(),"%d %d %d %d %d %d", 
    &servoPositions[0], &servoPositions[1],&servoPositions[2],
    &servoPositions[3], &servoPositions[4],&servoPositions[5]);

//print positions again
Serial.println("Parsed servo positions:");

for(int i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    Serial.print("position ");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(": ");
    Serial.println(servoPositions[i]);
}
```

Outputs

```
Parsed servo positions:
position 0: 180
position 1: 0
position 2: 0
position 3: 0
position 4: 90
position 5: 90
```